# Sending Email Using Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to send an email using Python:

```
import smtplib

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail('xxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com', ['xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'], 'HELLO')
s.quit()
```

But this error pops up:

```
     server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 311, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 286, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Is it not working because Gmail is blocking me? I don't want to connect to other mail servers to send my email. Is it still possible without them?

Comment: Do you have an SMTP server on `localhost`?

Comment: Change `smtplib.SMTP('localhost')` to `smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 465)`

Comment: No i thought python automatically creates a stmpserver. And i dont want to connect to google mail server.  is it possible to send it without logging on other mail servers?

Comment: Well, then create your own email server.

Comment: @user3312428 yes but first, you need to have a MTA installed on your server and second your emails are probably going to be flagged as spam.

Comment: So STMPServer/stmpd can't send the mail without MTA?

Answer (score 0):

change 'localhost' to 'smtp.gmail.com'